# if constexpr with static_assert in lambda, which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, static-assert

When we want to use a `static_assert` in a `if constexpr` we must make the condition dependent on some template parameter. Interestingly, gcc and clang disagree when the code is wrapped in a lambda.

The following code compiles with gcc, but clang triggers the assert, even if the `if constexpr` can't be true.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T> constexpr std::false_type False;

template<typename T>
void foo() {

    auto f = [](auto x) {
        constexpr int val = decltype(x)::value;
        if constexpr(val < 0) {
            static_assert(False<T>, "AAA");
        }
    };

    f(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{});
}

int main() {
    foo<int>();
}
```

[Live example here](https://godbolt.org/z/dATy8D).

It can easily be fixed by substituting `False<T>` by `False<decltype(x)>`.

So the question is: which compiler is right? I'd assume that gcc is correct because the condition in the `static_assert` is dependent on `T`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This asks kind of the same question but coming from the opposite direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393908/if-constexpr-why-is-discarded-statement-fully-checked.

Comment: gcc optimizes the lambda out as you aren't doing anything with it. The call f(...) is optimized out as well of course.

Comment: @NathanOlivier nope. However, write auto foo() { ... return f (... ) ; } and it will trigger the static_assert.

Comment: @mfnx [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/3eWdMJ).  Can you share an example?

Comment: I would say both are right (ill formed NDR): `static_assert(False<int>, "AAA");` is equivalent to `static_assert(false, "AAA");` inside the lambda.

Comment: @mfnx Can't reproduce, too.

Comment: @NathanOliver you could also compile with -O0 and you would see the same. Example returning f(...): https://wandbox.org/permlink/pgB8pfzv3Dfaqhjo

Comment: @Jarod42, this sounds reasonable. Do you have a reference in the standard?

Comment: @mfnx You've changed the value of the constant.  Using the OP's example where the constant is `f(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{});` Wandbox doesn't trigger the assert: https://wandbox.org/permlink/UFYAmYwtt1ptsndr

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes you are right, sorry for the noise. Seems gcc is just right as that code in the constexpr should be discarded if the constant >= 0;

Comment: GCC is correct after [P0588R1](https://wg21.link/p0588r1), IIUC (see [P0588R0](https://wg21.link/p0588r0) for its background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [[stmt.if]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if#2.sentence-3) (emphasis mine)

> If the if statement is of the form if constexpr, the value of the condition shall be a contextually converted constant expression of type bool; this form is called a constexpr if statement. If the value of the converted condition is false, the first substatement is a discarded statement, otherwise the second substatement, if present, is a discarded statement. **During the instantiation of an enclosing templated entity ([temp.pre]), if the condition is not value-dependent after its instantiation, the discarded substatement (if any) is not instantiated.**

Reading that one would think the static assert would be dropped, but this is not the case.

The static assert is triggered in the first phase of the template because the compiler know it's always false.

From [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8) (emphasis mine)

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. [ *Note:* Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked in this way. — *end note* ]
>   The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - (8.1) no valid specialization can be generated for a template **or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated**, or
>
> [...]

Yes indeed, your `False<T>` depends on `T`. The problem is that a generic lambda is itself a template, and `False<T>` is not dependent on any template parameter of the lambda.

For a `T` that `False<T>` is false, the static assert will always be false, no matter which template argument is sent to the lambda.

The compiler can see that for any instantiation of the template `operator()`, the static assert will always trigger for the current T. Hence the compiler error.

A solution for this would be to depend on `x`:

```
template<typename T>
void foo() {

    auto f = [](auto x) {
        if constexpr(x < 0) {
            static_assert(False<decltype(x)>, "AAA");
        }
    };

    f(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{});
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/arDA9D)

Answer (score 13):

The usual rule here is [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8):

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if: no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated

Once you instantiate `foo<T>`, the `static_assert` you have is no longer dependent. It becomes `static_assert(false)` - for all possible instantiations of the call operator of the generic lambda `f`. That's ill-formed, no diagnostic required. Clang diagnoses, gcc doesn't. Both are correct.

Note that it doesn't matter that the `static_assert` here *is* discarded.

> It can easily be fixed by substituting `False<T>` by `False<decltype(x)>`.

This keeps the `static_assert` dependent within the generic lambda, and now we get into a state where there could hypothetically be a valid specialization, so we're no longer ill-formed, ndr.