# Is it possible to remove control flow statements with if constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I'm testing the possibilities of `if constexpr` and I was wondering if it was possible to remove control flow statements with it.

The code I'm testing is:

```
int main() {
    void *indirect_label;
    if constexpr (false) {
       goto label; // Rejected by MSVC, clang and GCC
    }
    if constexpr (false) {
        continue;  // Rejected by clang and GCC
    }
    if constexpr (false) {
        break; // Rejected by clang and GCC
    }
    if constexpr (false) {
        goto *indirect_label; // Rejected by clang and MSVC
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I added a test for the indirect gotos language extension implemented by GCC and clang.

Considering that `if constexpr` should discard the statements if the condition is false, why does MSVC and GCC accept some parts of the code (but different) and clang rejects all four.

What behaviour is correct?

Comment: Sitting back and waiting for someone to completely miss the point of the question and start freaking out over the `goto`s.

Comment: Do note that `if constexpr` is meant to be used with templates.  If the code is not dependent then body is still compiled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393908/if-constexpr-why-is-discarded-statement-fully-checked

Comment: Where is `label` defined?  And can you [edit] into the question a sample of the error messages you get from the compilers?

Comment: None of these control statements make sense in the context in which they are used. You cannot use `continue;` or `break;` at these points and `label` does not exist. Indirect gotos are not standard C++.

Comment: I was wondering if `if constexpr` could remove them. I am using this to implement a few macros.

Comment: If you could show us what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to help you out with that.

Comment: @NathanOliver: What he's trying to achieve is obvious: he wants to use `if constexpr` to eliminate code. Why is kind of irrelevant; he's asking about the powers of `if constexpr`.

Comment: I'm trying to "forward" control flow from a function to another. Imagine returning an object of type `cf<break_loop>` and then a macro using `if constexpr` to issue a `break` statement.

Comment: @NicolasBértolo: That's not even *close* to a power of `if constexpr`. Functions are isolated from each other, and `if constexpr` changes nothing about it.

Comment: Of course. It seems I did not explain myself correctly. If `if constexpr` cannot do this then I will have to implement it using many more macros than I'd like, one for each combination of control flow statements possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if constexpr` is not a macro. Indeed, it only gains powers distinct from a regular `if` statement in the *specific circumstances* of both being in a template and the condition itself being based on template parameters. And even then, the discarded statements have to be at least potentially legitimate.

Comment: What exactly should be understood by "*potentially legitimate*"?

Comment: @Fureeish: The rules for discarded statements are extremely complicated and probably best dealt with in a separate question. The gist of it is basically "ignore the question of whether a template could be instantiated with those argument; if all of them work out, is it still legit C++?" `goto label_that_doesnt_exist` is most definitely never going to be legitimate C++. Same goes for `continue` or `break` in a place where those aren't allowed.

Comment: So is it a bug in MSVC that it accepts `break` and `continue` outside a loop?

Comment: Also, `break;` statements are valid only inside loops and `switch` statements. `continue;` statements are valid only inside loops.