# Implement assert without preprocessor in C++20

Tags: c++, preprocessor, assertion, c++20

C++ knows `assert()` which allows runtime checks that compile to nothing in dependence of `NDEBUG`.

I would like to replace that macro using compiler-code and avoiding the preprocessor. I need to do the following:

- Break or terminate if expressions evaluates to `false`
- Log the code line where the assert is called
- Discard the check and the passed expression for `NDEBUG` builds

Breaking/terminating the application is easy.

In C++20 there is `std::experimental::source_location` which I can use to get the code location of the assertion.

A compile time conditional could be done using `requires` or `constexpr if`

However I do not know how I could avoid the evaluation of the expression. When implementing `myAssert(expression)` as a function, I need to pass the expression result as a function argument which means it is evaluated anyway, even if the parameter is not used inside the function.

Is there a way to solve this in C++20?

EDIT: A templated example:

```
template <typename T> requires (gDebug)
void assertTrue(const T& pResult, const std::experimental::source_location& pLocation) noexcept
{
   if (!static_cast<bool>(pResult))
   {
      // error handling
   }
}

template <typename T> requires (!gDebug)
void assertTrue(const T&) noexcept
{
}
```

Comment: can you show an example? I am a bit confused by not evaluating the expression, but evaluating the expression anyhow

Comment: This is one of the few jobs for a macro.  You should use the tool that fits the job.  Also, `assert` is a run time thing, `if constexpr` requires compile time.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes. The check itself is runtime. However removing the check in NDEBUG build is compile time.

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe the condition of `if constexpr` should serve as a (compile-time) switch for enabling/disabling assertion itself.

Comment: Did `assert` or the preprocessor offend you in some way? They've been working fine for the rest of us for decades.

Comment: @NathanOliver Maybe your are right. I am mainly just curious. However macros also have real drawbacks like problems with commas in expressions.

Comment: @DanielLangr Aha, that makes sense.  Unfortuneltly that gets in the way of having the ability to: *Discard the check and the passed expression for NDEBUG builds*

Comment: @Silicomancer *"commas in expression"* Well, that's a problem only with the standard `assert`. You can write your own one using `...` and `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: Nothing can depend on `NDEBUG` without depending on the preprocessor because `NDEBUG` is a preprocessor macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about the case when you disabled debugging and you want the function to be a noop. I see 2 options:

You can use a macro. Macros can be misused, but they have their place and "passing an expression" without evaluating it is a case for a macro.

Alternatively, pass a callable that returns the result you want to assert for. Only call it when `gDebug == True`:

```
template <typename F> requires (gDebug)
void assertTrue(const F& f, const std::experimental::source_location& pLocation) noexcept
{
   if (!static_cast<bool>(f()))
   {
      // error handling
   }
}
```

Though this will make the call rather verbose. For example one that fails always:

```
assertTrue( [](){ return false; });
```

Comment: Do note that you macro will only work in template functions where `gDebug` is a dependent value.  Otherwise the statement is not discarded.

Comment: @NathanOliver dont understand completely. Are you saying that `if constexpr (false) foo();` will not be discarded?

Comment: Yes.  `if constexpr` only works in template code.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393908/if-constexpr-why-is-discarded-statement-fully-checked/59394147#59394147

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, decided to simply remove the macro from the answer