# How can I move or assign one vector into another depending of their type using if constexpr?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

I wanted to move or assign a `std::vector<Scalar>` into a `std::vector<float>` depending on the type `Scalar`.

If `Scalar` is `float` then move, else copy.

I tried this code

```cpp
#include <vector>

using Scalar = double;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Scalar> x(10);
    std::vector<float> y(10);

    if constexpr(std::is_same<Scalar, float>::value)
        y = std::move(x); // line 11 (does not compile)
    else
        y.assign(x.begin(), x.end());

    return 0;
}
```

but I get

```
main.cpp:11:24: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<float>’ and ‘std::remove_reference<std::vector<double>&>::type’ {aka ‘std::vector<double>’})
   11 |         y = std::move(x);
      |                        ^
```

I thought that since `std::is_same<Scalar, float>::value` is evaluated to `false` at compile-time, then the line below would not be compiled.

I compiled it using `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o exec`.

How can I move/assign `x` into `y` depending on the `Scalar` type?

Comment: `if constexpr` only does the magic inside of templates, when the condition depends on a template parameter.

Comment: "the magic" that HolyBlackCat refers to is the discarding of the code in the untaken branch.  Your `if` statement is still constexpr, but both branches are instantiated.  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if constexpr - why is discarded statement fully checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393908/if-constexpr-why-is-discarded-statement-fully-checked)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out [by HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852001/how-can-i-move-or-assign-one-vector-into-another-depending-of-their-type-using-i#comment135484010_76852001) in a comment, and as stated in cppref: "Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked." (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

Here is one potential solution involving one new template function

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <typename U, typename V>
void move_or_copy(std::vector<U>& y, std::vector<V>&& x) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same<U,V>::value) {
        y = std::move(x);
    } else {
        y.assign(x.begin(), y.end());
    }
}


using Scalar = double;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Scalar> x(10);
    std::vector<float> y(10);

    move_or_copy(y, x);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Because `main()` isn't a template, both sides of the `if constexpr` must be valid.  To use `if constexpr` this way, it needs to be in a template.

Thankfully, a good template makes this logic more reusable:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename U>
void move_or_copy(std::vector<T>& dest, std::vector<U>&& src)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,U>)
        dest = std::move(src);
    else
        dest.assign(src.begin(), src.end());
}



using Scalar = double;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Scalar> x(10);
    std::vector<float> y(10);

    move_or_copy(y, std::move(x));
}
```

We could make the template function better constrained (allow any collection as source), but this should at least provide the correct direction in which to depart.

Comment: Yep, and with collections as template params `template <typename Container1, typename Container2>` second arg would be real forwarding reference. Currently e.g. `move_or_copy(y, y);` is not possible.

Answer (score 9):

The assignment `y = std::move(x);` is not valid when `Scalar` is not `float`, because `y` is of type `std::vector<float>` and `x` is of type `std::vector<Scalar>`, and they are not directly compatible.

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

using Scalar = double;

template <typename T, typename A>
void moveOrAssign(std::vector<T>& dest, std::vector<A>&& source) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, A>) {
        dest = std::move(source);
    } else {
        dest.assign(source.begin(), source.end());
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Scalar> x(10);
    std::vector<float> y(10);

    moveOrAssign(y, std::move(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is more elegant than the other one, because it doesn't require overload resolution and is overall short and more intuitive.

Comment: But this code is wrong, or I don't know how to copy-paste? https://godbolt.org/z/9xrhvP176 Both vectors use the same template param `T` and `float` conflicts with `double` .

Comment: u can add new `typename` and use it !!

Comment: This would be a great solution if you edited out the errors

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/YMonEMefn

Comment: Since `source` is an rvalue reference, the second case would be improved by using [`std::make_move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) to avoid copying the elements in cases where it might matter. For example the current `moveOrAssign` implementation might make redundant copies in the case of a `std::vector<std::string>` and won't work at all in the case of a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<...>>`.

Comment: Your description may be true, but does not describe what the OP is confused by.  To be clear: your description applies to the code you posted as well!  So it doesn't describe why the code you posted succeeds, while the OP's code fails.